# Mobile tuning / Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, user-agent, ejs

In order to tune for mobiles a web site based on `Node.js`, I want to access `HTTP_USER_AGENT`. What is the best the way to go?

I have already set these in my code (index.js):

```
var useragent = require('useragent');
.....
app.get('/', function (request, response) {
var agent = useragent.parse(request.headers['user-agent']);
.....
```

Now I need to extract what will allow me to know if the user is in on a phone (for instance) or not. I also need to add some code in the index.ejs file.
What is the simplest way I can use for that?

Comment: useragent sniffing is fraught with inaccuracy - however, "mobile" detection seems to be one valid reason for such sniffing - I trust MDN docs because they are clear, concise and rarely wrong - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent#Mobile_Tablet_or_Desktop

Comment: This information is useful, but I basically know it. My question is about which code to use in the 2 files index.js ans index.ejs for it to work.

Comment: I addressed `know if the user is in on a phone (for instance) or not` in a comment because I have no answer for the rest, sorry

Comment: All right. Thanks then.